# All pages have 302 redirect, which I can't remove

Tags: multisite, redirect

I’ve got this site setup as a multisite with the main domain being http://www.scottish-orienteering.org.

If I enter a page without the www at the start it always 302 redirects to the homepage with a www rather than the current page. For example https://scottish-orienteering.org/example will direct to http://www.scottish-orienteering.org with a 302 redirect. This happens on everypage, and I want it to redirect to the same page with the www.

I’ve tried disabling all plugins, changing the theme and also removing the .htaccess file but it still does this.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking, it’s driving me mad.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Because you are using multisite, there are a few other places your site may have the WWW active. I would look in the following:

1. wp-config.php under "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE". [info](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/#step-4-enabling-the-network)
2. wp-config.php under "WP_HOME" and/or "WP_SITEURL" [info](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php)
3. Inside the database under the "{prefix}_site" (wp_site) table [info](https://deliciousbrains.com/wordpress-multisite-database-tour/#wp_site)
4. Inside the database under the "{prefix}_blogs" (wp_blogs) table [info](https://deliciousbrains.com/wordpress-multisite-database-tour/#wp_blogs)

**Failing those sources, I would check your hosting company. Do they do any domain routing, and if so, which domain do they have flagged under your account - www or non-www?**

Hope this helps.